# Is there a way to decouple a csv generator in my code that doesn't close the file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I wanted to write the following to decouple a data feed from the rest of my program, but it doesn't work throwing error - "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file."

```
class Feed:
    def __init__(self, data_loc=None):
        self.data_loc = data_loc
        with open(self.data_loc, newline='') as f:
            self.reader = csv.reader(f)

    def get_next_tick(self):
        return next(self.reader)


raw_data_loc = '{path to file}'

feed = Feed(data_loc=raw_data_loc)

print(feed.get_next_item())
```

I understand that after **init** is run the file closes and hence the error, but is there a way of achieving the separation of this csv generator in my code?

Comment: Do you want to explicitly not use the "with open()" statement again in your get_next_tick method?

Comment: in constructor you can do `self.reader = csv.reader(open(self.data_loc, 'r', newline=''))`

Comment: The `with` statement automatically closes the file... that's the whole point of using file-objects as context managers. Just don't do that if you don't want it to close.

Comment: Thanks all, will chew on that and see if it solves. @Jonas, no I'm not against using it in get_next_tick method.

Comment: @AndrejKesely that did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: to dive a bit deeper into the `with` statement, checkout [Context Managers](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html).

Comment: Thanks @KyleG I will do that

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment, you can implement `Feed` as a context manager like so:

```
class Feed:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.file_obj = open(*args, **kwargs)
        self.reader = csv.reader(self.file_obj)
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.close()
    def get_next_tick(self):
        return next(self.reader)
    def close(self):
        self.file_obj.close()
```

To print the first line of the feed we can do the following:

```
with Feed('feed.csv') as feed:
    print(feed.get_next_tick())
```

Because we used a context manager, the `__exit__` method is called even if the feed is empty and raises a `StopIteration` exception.

If you want to be able to iterate over the feed, you can add `__next__` and `__iter__` methods like so:

```
class Feed:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.file_obj = open(*args, **kwargs)
        self.reader = csv.reader(self.file_obj)
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.close()
    def __next__(self):
        return self.get_next_tick()
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def get_next_tick(self):
        return next(self.reader)
    def close(self):
        self.file_obj.close()
```

This will allow you to loop over your feed or even call `next(feed)` directly, eg:

```
with Feed('feed.csv') as feed:
    for item in feed:
        print(item)
```

Python Tips has a great [chapter on using Context Managers](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html), which were introduced in [PEP343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).